# C - void function(void), parameters and return values

Tags: c, syntax, parameters, return-value, void

I was given a large C-file containing several functions declared as follows:

```
void function_a(void);
```

The functions are written above the main program:

```
static void function_a(void) { .... }
```

Within the main program these functions are called as:

```
function_a();
```

Now as far as I know a function declared as written above does neither use parameters, nor have return values. However within these functions variables and arrays are used, which are not defined within these functions, but only in the main program.

Is this really correct C-Syntax? How can the functions access data from the main program, if it is not handed over as a parameter?

In addition the main program uses variables, which are calculated within the functions it calls.

Comment: Are they defined in the main *function*, or in the *file*?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited. They are defined in the file above the main function

Comment: Please post a complete example instead of fragments.

Comment: Do you know what a variable with static scope is?

Comment: If variables are defined "above" `main()` and "above" `function_a()` - and all are in the same file - then the variables can be accessed from both functions.   Any basic textbook on C will tell you that.

Comment: Does it compile without errors? -> valid syntax and even grammar. Is it good style? Possibly not. It depends. Impossible to judge without further information.

Comment: @StoryTeller: There is no such thing as "static scope". You most likely mean ["file scope"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1p2), less likely "static storage duration".

Comment: @Olaf I was thinking of both, and as usual formulated my comment as a mishmash...

Comment: @StoryTeller: "file scope" implies static storage duration, so the first alone is fine:-)

Answer (score 5):

Can you provide more context, please? In C you cannot access variables from another function but you can access global ones.

The following program is valid and will output 3, since `i` is a global variable and is visible everywhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 2;

void plusone() {
        i = i + 1;
}

int main() {
        plusone();
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
}
```

On the other side, the program below won't compile because `i` is local to `main()` function and is invisible elsewhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void plusone() {
        i = i + 1;
}

int main() {
        int i = 2;
        plusone();
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
}
```

Said that, usage of global variables is a bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: Okay. What if I have another C-File containing only variable definitions and link this file to my C-File containing the main program and the other functions. Are the variables from the separate C-File also global?

Comment: @J.M. you would have to declare those variables as `extern` so you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

So this:

```
//file_a.c
void function_a(void)
{
    //...
}
```

Makes `function_a` a function that does not take any arguments and does not return any values. This function may be used by all other functions in the same file `function_a` was declared or in any other `.c` file that you tell the compiler to put together into the final program.

In other words, this function is accessible to all translation units of your program. If you have this function in a file called `file_a.c`, and you also have another file called `file_z.c` you can do this:

```
//file_z.c
void function_z(void)
{
    function_a();
}
```

And all is fine.

On the other hand, this

```
//file_b.c
static void function_b(void)
{
    //...
}
```

(and I renamed the function for clarity)

Makes `function_b` a function that does not take any arguments and does not return any values, just like `function_a`. However, it also says that `function_b` has static-file scope in the translation unit that begins or includes`file_b.c`. That means it cannot be accessed by other translation units.

So if you now tried to do this in `file_z.c`:

```
void function_z(void)
{
    function_b();
}
```

You would get compilation errors:

```
file_z.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `function_b'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Because each `file_{a,b,z}.c` is (or probably should be) the starting point of their own separate translation units, and `function_b` was declared with static-file scope in `file_b.c`, this function simply "does not exist" for other translation units.

Now, as to the variables declared just before `function_b`, I take they look somewhat like this:

```
//file_a.c
int array[10];
void function_a(void)
{
    //...
}
```

That simply declares a global variable. It can be accessed by all functions in `file_a.c`, provided that they appear *after* the declaration. It can also be used by other translation units (like `file_b.c` or `file_z.c`) if you declare it like this:

```
//file_b.c
extern int array[10];
```

When you compile everything togheter, that declaration in the translation unit that starts with `file_b.c` will tell the compiler that `array` is not a file-scope variable within that `file_b.c`; rather the compiler will have to look for that variable in another translation unit, and then link them together so that all functions do the same thing to that block of 10 integers.

Answer (score 0):

In C it is not at all possible to access local variables of another function or even scope.
Is the code compiling correctly? If yes these variables must be global defined either in the beginning or some header file.
If not make them global to access from non-parametric functions.

Comment: another function has another scope so your first sentence is a bit redundant.

Comment: Of course you can access variables of your parent scope.